# Why does this function not get called but after its his turn again it gets called this time

Tags: func, godot

I am making a turn based game, currently I am trying to add a critical hit system it shows that it is doing critical hit damage but doesnt play the critical hit function,the thing that doesnt make sense too me is, it gets called when its his turn again so something in the first turn is making the function not be called but gets called at the second time, It seems to be who ever attacks first doesnt get the dialogue function to be called, but plays fine after the first turn.

```
func check_if_player(attacker, target):
    if attacker == player_node:
        print(attacker.move_slot[move_index].name)
        dialogue_text.text = (attacker.name + " is attacking")
        dialogue_ani.play("TextScroll")
        target.take_damage(attacker.move_slot[move_index],attacker)
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(2), "timeout")
        _update_view()
        if attacker.crit:
            attacker.crit = false  # Where I turn it off
            print(attacker.crit)
            yield(critical_hit(attacker),"completed")
    else:
        yield(attack(attacker, target), "completed")
        
func attack(attacker, target):
    var random_move = randi() % 3 + 1
    print(attacker.move_slot[move_index].name)
    dialogue_text.text = (attacker.name + " is attacking")
    dialogue_ani.play("TextScroll")
    target.take_damage(attacker.move_slot[random_move],attacker) # Calls the function to take damage
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(2), "timeout") #Wait for 2 seconds
    _update_view()
    if attacker.crit:
        attacker.crit = false # Where I turn it off
        print(attacker.crit)
        yield(critical_hit(attacker),"completed")
```

these two functions is how I check if the player is attacking I need to do this because I want the player to use a selected move, if isnt player then play enemy attack

and this is my monster script, where I detect if a critical hit happens, I should say this the monster script is a resource and is separate from the other script, where player, enemy and critical hit function is all in one script.

```
func take_damage(move,attacker):
    randomize()
    var critical = 1
    #var critical_chance = randi() % 100 + 1
    var critical_chance = 5
    if critical_chance <= 99.25:
        crit = true
        critical = 2
        
    var type : float = Get_effectiveness(move.type,type_1) * Get_effectiveness(move.type,type_2)
    var modifier : float = rand_range(0.85,1.0) * type * critical
    var a : float = (2.0 * attacker.level / 5.0 + 2.0)
    var b : float = (a * attacker.attack * move.power / defence) / 50.0
    var c : float = (b + 2.0) * modifier
    var damage = int(c)
    current_health -= damage
    print(str(attacker.name) + " = " + str(damage))
    #print(a)
    #print(b)
```

Currently I have it pretty much be true every time the player or enemy attacks so it should call/ show the critical hit function, I turn the crit bool to false in the first few functions so it should only happen once

This is the function that adds text to the screen it also prints it to tell me its working but it doesnt print it, if its the first attacking monster, am I making a noobie mistake here?

```
func critical_hit(attacker):
    dialogue_text.text = (attacker.name + " has landed a critical hit!")
    dialogue_ani.play("TextScroll")
    print(attacker.name + " has landed a critical hit!")
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(3), "timeout")
```

Comment: I decided to add a return at the end instead though I dont know if thats the better option, return critical > 1 # I have placed this at the end of the take_damage() function but it seems to work for now.

Comment: I believe, `crit = true` should be `attacker.crit = true`. But yeah, storing `crit` probably not a good idea. By the way, you are repeating yourself. One of the reasons [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is pushed for is that you can forget to update something on one of the copies. In this case, it appears you forgot to replace `move_index` with `random_move` in `attack`. Instead you can make it a parameter. By the way, I suspect you are using timers and the "timeout" signal to wait for the `AnimationPlayer`, you could use its `animation_finished` signal instead.

Comment: Oh I see, attacker.crit = true makes a lot more sense and why it wasnt doing what I wanted, and move_index is correct, because I have 4 buttons and the monster has an array that the buttons align too, so when a button is pressed it is also the correct move I want the player to use, while the enemy just picks a random move to attack with. you said dont repeat my self, I assume you are talking about how I check if the player is attacking or the enemy, do you have an idea on how I can make this less repeitive while also having the option for the player to select a move and the enemy having it own

Comment: Look the third line of `attack`, it says `print(attacker.move_slot[move_index].name)`, should that not be `random_move`? I still believe you forgot to change it. As to make it less repetitive, I said to use a parameter. In this case, make `move_index` a parameter of `attack`. Then in the other method, you can check if it is the player, if it is, pass what the player picked. Otherwise use random and pass whatever random picked.

Comment: Oh I see it now, it didnt make much difference other then making a mistake on what move the enemy made but thanks anyways could of caused issues in the future and I see what you mean now about it being repetitive I already have attack so why not just add a parameter too it, thanks I am only have around 1 and a half years of experience with godot but you sure have made it alot easier, before even making this turn base system I never used returns now I see how useful they are!